# Cannot connect to Wifi on ubuntu

Tags: networking, wireless

I turned my laptop on it didn't connect to the wifi.

I turned everything off and on again several times and nothing has happened.

I've tried checking the settings and got nothing.

my smart phone has no problem connecting to it. Just my Ubuntu that doesn't want to let me use my wifi.

Can someone please help???

Comment: edit your question and post output of these commands: `rfkill list`,  `ip link`, `lspci`, `dmesg | grep net`

Comment: Ok thanks wild man. I tried that and it said nothing was bloked and i still cant get online. – adam

Comment: Please [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result.

Answer (score 0):

It may be the problem due to WIFI hardware switch turned off.Please the try the following to get it rectified

Type the following in terminal

```
rfkill unblock all
```

To confirm anything is off.Please do the following

```
rfkill list all
```

This may help you

Comment: Ok thanks wild man. I tried that and it said nothing was bloked and i still cant get online.

Comment: The question is not clear.It didn't mention any softblock.So my answer will help if there is any softblock